# Data passing design pattern of structured data in C#, why not public variables

Tags: c#, oop, class, design-patterns, struct

How to implement the following pattern "nicely": (with a hint of arrrgh why can't I just use public variables)

I have a chunk of data that one set of classes can produce and another set of classes can consume. There are multiple ways to produce and consume this data. The data set has a fixed hierachical structure with value fields on multiple levels. I have numbers, enums, strings.

So, in the prototype version of my application, I jotted a bunch of classes together in a completely public fashion:

```
public class AllData
{
    public IdentifyData identifyData;
    public FirmwareData firmwareData;
    public VersionData versionData;

    public TestData testData;
    public ServiceData serviceData;
    public ErrorLog errorLog;

    public AllData()
    {
        identifyData = new IdentifyData();
        versionData = new VersionData();
        firmwareData = new FirmwareData();
        testData = new TestData();
        serviceData = new ServiceData();
        errorLog = new ErrorLog();
    }

}

(...)

public class FirmwareData
{
    public DataStatus status;

    public int build;
    public int variant;

    public FirmwareData()
    {
        status = new DataStatus();
    }
}      

(Etc.)
```

Now I'm doing the real version of the software and want to do things right, so I started property'ing everything. However, I feel the code takes a hit by doing this. It gets large and ugly and the benefit is not appearent in my case.

I thought about using structs instead, but I really don't want to pass all this data by value all the time. Besides, there are some range and sanity checks here and there I need to do.

Any clues on how to implement this data model in a nice way? (beware that I'm not very experienced in OOP and C#)

If possible, I would like to have the data become readonly when it is handed over to consumer classes, how could one do that?

Thanks and best regards

Lars

Comment: er.... just add `{get;set;}` to the end to make properties - not that ugly; or `{get;private set;}` if you don't want external code to set it...? maybe `{get;internal set;}` if you don't want code in different assemblies to be able to use the setters...?

Comment: Yeah, that's not so bad. But can I do that with .NET framework 2.0? (using Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: yes; that is a language feature, not a runtime feature - the C# 4 compiler is fine with that, even when targeting .NET 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do don't use `struct`s.  *Especially* if they're mutable!

Just use properties - they are generally preferable over fields (especially if you intend to use front-end systems that use, say `TypeDescriptor` to get component information - Asp.Net MVC does this).

My starting rule here is that if it's public or protected (in most cases) I'll use a property.  If it's protected or private ***and immutable*** then I'll consider using a readonly field.  There are always exceptions to that rule though, it's just my own starting point.  I will *rarely ever* use a public field except in helper classes for unit tests.

The read-only question is a different matter, and realistically can only be solved if you *do* use properties.

I would use read-only interfaces:

```
public interface IMyData
{
   int Value { get; }
}
```

And then your classes can be read/write if you need them to be:

```
public class MyData : IMyData
{
  public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The interface is implemented - code that uses and understands `MyData` (i.e. your producer) can write to it, but the code that only needs to read just uses the interface.  Using an abstraction like this also has the added benefit of allowing your consumer code to consume your data in any form.  E.g. You can add interface implementations to entity types generated by EF if that's your chosen ORM.

Be aware, though, that you can't always enforce read-only across the board - especially if you intend to use types like generic Dictionaries etc.

For objects that really must always be immutable after construction then use constructors and hide the setter.  So on the `MyData` class again:

```
 public int Value { get; private set; }     

 public MyData(int value){
   Value = value;
 }
```

Granted, you can also use a readonly field for this (but neither approach will actually prevent someone who really wants to modify your object being able to do so, since both approaches can be subverted with reflection).

Comment: Thanks for an enlightening answer. The read only interface is a great idea that I might try. But it will still bloat my current fully functional code into triple or quadruple size ;)    (it always annoys me when doing things the recommended way means a huge increase in lines of code)

Comment: Well - ask yourself, are you doing it the 'recommended way' because you *want* to, or because actually you *need* to in order to achieve your objective? If it's the second of these, then the 'bloat' (which I have to say I disagree with, a few interfaces here and there aren't an issue) you're talking about is actually necessary code. Or - to put it another way - you can't make a car out of only two wheels! :)

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are of no use here, this regards how you want to organize your classes and their relationships.

Start by declaring all the fields as `private` and expose in the class methods to "do things" with the data, or is some cases to return them, but try to avoid that clients can directly access the fields and maybe change them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)

This is just a starting point.

Comment: Well, initially I thought about having the data carrying classes perform the data parsing tasks and only exposing the results read only. BUT we have different ways of aquiring this data with different processing involved, so I really only want the mentioned classes to be data carriers.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout of your data will be fixed for all time and doesn't need any arrays, an exposed-field struct may be a perfect fit.  The notion that fields should be encapsulated in properties is good when applied to classes, but is often bad when applied to structures.  Fundamentally, a struct is a collection of fields bound together with duct tape.  If `struct1` and `struct2` are the same struct type, the statement `struct1 = struct2` will mutate `struct1` by overwriting all its fields with the values of the corresponding ones in `struct2`.  Nothing in the definition of the structure type type can possibly change that.  Given that all fields of a structure are always publicly exposed to mutation via bulk assignment, it may be better to have a struct which advertises itself as a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape than to have one that pretends to be something else.

The biggest problem with using exposed-field structures is ironically their biggest asset: many convenient ways of using exposed-field structures (especially nested ones) have no convenient equivalents when using other data types.  If one has an array of some nested struct type and wishes to update an inner element, one can do something like:

```
  TriangleList[index].Vertex1.X += 4;
```

and update part of the element in place.  If one replaces the array with a `List<TriangleStruct>`, the code would have to become:

```
  var temp = TriangleList[index];
  temp.Vertex1.X += 4;
  TriangleList[index] = temp;
```

Still not too bad.  Suppose, however, that one needed to change the type to support arbitrary polygons.  One could no longer represent the type with an exposed-field structure (if it contained an array, copying the struct would not copy the array but merely a reference; changing a coordinate in one copy of the struct would thus change it for both, likely leading to nasty bugs).  Any code to manipulate the struct which was predicated upon its being usable like an exposed-field structure would have to be totally rewritten.

In deciding whether to use an exposed-field struct or some other data type, consider the extent to which being able to use the convenient forms of access will be helpful, and the likelihood that the structure might change.  If the way the thing is used would mean that its semantics couldn't change without rewriting just about all the code that uses it, and it would be more convenient to access it as a struct, then use an exposed field struct.  There's no reason to make your code more cumbersome in order to accommodate future changes that are never going to happen if YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It).